# Spring boot "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext" with jndi configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I have create a spring-boot application which consider web and jpa dependencies.
I will deploy application to weblogic server. 
I am getting error while making data-source configuration with jndi in `application.resources` config file:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name = java:jdbc/MyDatasourceDS
```

Here the exception detail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/melbusatDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/melbusatDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/melbusatDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/melbusatDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

Comment: *Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:jdbc/melbusatDS'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial*

Comment: Is this when deploying or just running the embedded container?

Comment: Did you try giving your jndi-name as "java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatasourceDS"